# SQLITE - Get Top 5 paid customers from Bill Table

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have Bill Table with rowid, customer mobile and amount field. Bill table can have any number of entries for particular mobile number. I want to extract top 5 customers order by amount paid.

```
Table Bill
-----------------------------------
id     mobile  amount
-----------------------------------
1       8800    100
2       2244    200
3       8800    50
4       2134    100
5       2244    500
6       6789    100   
7       2134    50
8       2244    100
9       8800    200
```

Note - First I want to make sum of all amount paid by particular customer, then order them in descending order then get top 5 out of that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
select mobile, sum(amount) as total_amount 
from Bill 
group by mobile 
order by total_amount 
desc limit 5
```